# Searching Lists in R based on closest date

Tags: r, list, date, search, indexing

Currently trying to write some that would return the last date from an ordered list that is less than date X.

Right now I have this: it gets a list of days, and gets an index off the day we're going to be doing search on and range of how many dates we want to go back.

After that it checks if the date exists or not (e.g. Feb 30th). If the date doesn't exist, it decreases the date by 1 and then applies filter again (otherwise it tries to subtract 1 day from `NA` and fails).

```
library(lubridate)
getDate <- function(dates,day,range){
    if(range == 'single')
        {return (day-1)}

    z <- switch(range,
        single = days(1),
        month = days(30),
        month3 = months(3),
        month6 = months(6),
        year = years(1)
        )

    new_day <-(dates[day]-z)
    i <- 1
    while (is.na(new_day)){
        new_day <- dates[day] - days(i) - z 
    }
    ind<-which.min(abs (diff <-(new_day-dates)))

    if (diff[ind] < 0)
    {ind <- ind -1}

    return (ind[1])
}
```

While this function works, the problem is the speed efficiency. I have a feeling that `which.min(abs())` is far from the quickest and I'm wondering if there are any better alternatives (outside of also writing my own function to search lists).

```
stocks <- list(structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L,
18L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L), mon = c(0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), year = c(108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L,
108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L,
108L, 108L, 108L), wday = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), yday = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L,
8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L,
31L, 34L, 35L, 36L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min",
"hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), tzone = "UTC",
class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")))

old_pos <- getDate(stocks[[1]],21,"month") #should return 0
old_pos <- getDate(stocks[[1]],22,"month") #should return 1
```

This does not return a vector, nor a date, only an index and the main question isn't about working (which it does), but optimizing it.

The value is later on being used in another function, one possible speed up is to first match all of the old indexes to new ones and then return that as another list. However not sure if it would offer any speed up.

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data for testing.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sDXMSft6 or 
http://pastebin.com/vLVvwjHd

(The only value being passed in as stocks is stocks[[1]])

Comment: Rather than pasting a link to printed data, please provide the output from `dput(head(stocks[[1]],20))` and an example of how we should call your `getDate` function. Then your question would contain a minimal, [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616).

Comment: @Gray_Hound you can be inspired by my answer t create a reproducible example with the expected result. Creating a good example is generally half path to the solution.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tQDwPLip

Comment: I agree with the others who are encouraging you to improve how you ask a question.  There is too much irrelevant code and excessive data in the question as it now appears.    Its not just a matter of dumping whatever you have onto SO but extracting the meat of it and asking just that.  I have answered @agstudy's reformulation of your question in my answer.  I suspect not many others would be willing to wade through what you have presented either.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I just shortened the data and adjusted the example.

Answer (score 3):

Using @agstudy's reformulation including `sDate` and `x.Date`

**data.table**

We can perform the calculations in data.table like this where the first column shows the original date in `sDate` and the second column is the corresponding `x.Date` date:

```
> library(data.table)
> data.table(date = x.Date, x.Date, key = "date")[J(sDate),, roll = TRUE]
         date     x.Date
1: 2003-02-03 2003-02-02
2: 2003-02-12 2003-02-10
3: 2003-02-16 2003-02-15
```

**sqldf** Using sqldf its like this:

```
> library(sqldf)
> sDateDF <- data.frame(sDate = sDate)
> xDateDF <- data.frame(xDate = x.Date)
> 
> sqldf("select s.sdate sDate, max(x.xdate) xDate 
+   from sDateDF s join xDateDF x on x.xDate <= s.sDate 
+   group by s.sDate")
       sDate      xDate
1 2003-02-03 2003-02-02
2 2003-02-12 2003-02-10
3 2003-02-16 2003-02-15
```

**zoo**

Using zoo, we create two zoo series, merge them and use na.locf like this.  The result is the `x.Date` corresponding to each `sDate` (i.e. the second column in either of the above solutions):

```
> library(zoo)
>
> zx <- zoo(seq_along(x.Date), x.Date)
> zs <- zoo(seq_along(sDate), sDate)
> x.Date[na.locf(merge(zx, zs))[sDate, "zx"]]
[1] "2003-02-02" "2003-02-10" "2003-02-15"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you have a vector of dates, for example :

```
x.Date <- as.Date("2003-02-01") + c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14,20) 
"2003-02-02" "2003-02-04" "2003-02-08" "2003-02-10" "2003-02-15" "2003-02-21"
```

and giving a vector of dates, for example:

```
sDate <- as.Date("2003-02-01") + c(2,11,15)
```

You try to get the closer date in x.Date to this giving date but less than this date:

```
 lapply(sDate,function(x)max(x.Date[x.Date-x <=0]))
[[1]]
[1] "2003-02-02"

[[2]]
[1] "2003-02-10"

[[3]]
[1] "2003-02-15"
```

Comment: Yes, with only specific thing being that sDate is one of the dates in a list - one of the fixed time intervals.

Comment: @Gray_Hound I edit my answer. sDate is a list of dates now.

Comment: @agstudy `is.list(sDate)` is not `TRUE`.

Comment: @Roland yes right but I don't get your point... do you mean I `lapply(as.list(sDate),...)`

Comment: I just think we should try to be exact with terminology in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Roland it is not a vector neither ..I can't find the right terminology here.

Comment: @agstudy `is.vector(unclass(sDate)) == TRUE`.  It's a vector with an attribute.